# is there a powershell script that takes the first 3 zip folder sorted by date from a folder A and extracts them into a folder B?

Tags: powershell, zip

I need to take the first 3 zip folder sorted by date and then extract them into a specific folder
I tried this script but it doesn't work

```
percorso = Get-ChildItem -Path  'C:\first'| Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending 
ForEach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\first")[0..2]){Expand-Archive -DestinationPath 'C:\Users\second' -Force}
```

thanks

Comment: Please add your code and show where you need help in it, Nobody will write this script for you, but everybody will be happy to help you to fix it...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have already tried something, you should edit your question and paste in the code. Explain what works and what doesn't work. If you have error messages, paste these in too (in full). This way, we can respond to a  a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: sorry but I have attached the screenshot but I don't know why it is not shown

Comment: Don't try to paste code as image, instead paste it in the question as [Formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189) text.

Comment: It what way does it "not work"?

Comment: it asks me "Path: " in loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be the below. You weren't passing the source file path to Expand-Archive at all.

```
$AllFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path  'C:\first'| Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending 
ForEach ($File in $AllFiles[0..2]){
    Expand-Archive -Path $File -DestinationPath 'C:\Users\second' -Force}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but this script give me this error "The path "work1.zip" could not be found because it does not exist". The selection of the 3 folders by date works but the script doesnt unzip them

Comment: Hmm, try:
`Expand-Archive -Path $($File.FullName) -DestinationPath 'C:\Users\second' -Force`